# iOS: run app as a service in background

Tags: ios

Being relatively new to iOS App development, I wish to develop an app which runs like a service in background (comparable with android service).
 The goal of my app is to use the native voice recognition, also while the app is inactive.
 My question is, would it principally be possible to code an app to be able to run also in background?
 I've read in a few pretty old threads that iOS closes any app after three minutes. 
However, should it be possible, I would be thankful for any coding example.

Comment: There are limited background processing modes available on iOS to deal with situations like location, Bluetooth, VoIP, audio playback.  There is no ability to run an arbitrary "service" as there is on Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so, because if the app is on background, the local audio recogisation is for Siri.